# Flutter package barcode_scan -> Failed to notify project evaluation listener

Tags: android, flutter, barcode-scanner, androidx

After migrating my project to Androidx, i've got a build error because of the barcode_scan library.

I tried two Kotline Versions. Both 1.2.31 and 1.2.51 don't work.

```
    dependencies:
        flutter:
            sdk: flutter
        firebase_auth: any
        firebase_messaging: any
        flutter_html: any
        http: any
        intl: any
        cloud_firestore: any
        url_launcher: any
        share: any
        expandable: any
        qr_flutter: any
        qrcode_reader: any
        random_string: any
        barcode_scan: ^1.0.0
```

My buildscript in the project-level gradle file locks like this

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' 

    }
}
```

Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\davidw\OneDrive - BBBaden\Anlagen\Pfadi\App\dev\morea-master\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

> Configure project :app
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':barcode_scan'.

  > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
  >   java.lang.AbstractMethodError (no error message)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't exactly know why, and hopefully someone more experienced will comment on this, but I solved this exact problem by commenting this line out from my app-level gradle:

`implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"`

And changing the Kotlin version & Gradle version in the project-level gradle to:

`ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'`

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'`

I'm still getting `registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)`, but the app builds.

Comment: As i said, i am using a lib called barcode_scan, witch riquieres this kotlin plugin. Unfortunaly, this kotlin plugin seems to make flutter crash. The plugin works perfektly fine without this plugin.

Comment: I use barcode_scan too. It works with the said modifications, I can still scan QR codes.

Comment: How to use this plugin? There is no any example how to use it.

Comment: From docs: Simply call `var barcode = await BarcodeScanner.scan()` to scan a barcode